# Python: Mostrar una imagen recuperada de sqlite

Tags: python, sqlite

tengo problemas mostrando una imagen recuperada de una base de datos, de las columnas tipo BLOB, mi problema es que me regresa una cadena tipo byte y no se como convertirla a un array o semejante que pueda usar el imshow().
Espero puedan ayudarme, hay alguna forma de transformar ese valor de la base de datos a un array o parecido?

el Código que tengo utilizado es este:

```py
def crear_conexion(base_datos):
    try:
        conexion =sqlite3.connect(base_datos)
        return conexion
    except sqlite3.Error as error:
        print('Se ha producido un error en la conexion :(',error)

conexion =crear_conexion('CartasLoteria.db')

def recuperar_carta(conexion,id):
    sql ="SELECT * FROM Carta WHERE id =?;"
    
    cursor = conexion.cursor()
    cursor.execute(sql,(id,)) 
    
    registros = cursor.fetchall()   
    return registros


id_producto = 1
print('Registro con id %d' %id_producto) 
lista=recuperar_carta(conexion, id_producto)
binario=lista[0][3]
```

y lo que quiero imprimir es el binario, pero es una cadena de bytes muy larga.

Comment: Hola! Sería bueno que subieras el código explicandolo para que podamos ver lo que tienes y que es exactamente lo que ocurre. Te recomiendo leer [¿Cómo preguntar?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Así harás mejores preguntas y podrás ser ayudado en tus problemas!!

Comment: Voto por cerrar esta pregunta porque la pregunta no demuestra ninguna investigación ni esfuerzo.

Comment: Y respondiendo a Candid Moe, creeme si investigue anteriormente, preguntar en los foros es mi última opción, intente realizar este problema convirtiendo la cadena con struct, con fromstring, con frombytes, utilizando io pero de la forma incorrecta al parecer, utilizando with open('wb') pero eso solo me guardaba la imagen en mi computadora intentando pasar los  bytes a base 10 o uint8, entonces es solo como comentario

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seguramente ese BLOB sea directamente lo que habría dentro de un fichero, si la imagen estuviera guardada en fichero.

Quiero decir, imagina que la imagen está en el fichero "abulafia.png" y que lees el contenido del fichero directamente en modo binario con el código:

```
with open("abulafia.png", "rb") as f:
  image_bytes = f.read()
```

En este caso `image_bytes` contendría una cadena de bytes como la siguiente (he truncado su longitud porque es larga):

```
b'\x89PNG\r\n\x1a\n\x00\x00\x00\rIHDR\...\x00\x00\x00\x00IEND\xaeB`\x82'
```

Lo que quiero decir es que muy probablemente el BLOB que obtienes de tu base de datos sea una cadena similar. Como ves al principio de la cadena aparecen ciertos "bytes mágicos" que dan una pista sobre el formato de la imagen, en este caso PNG.

En general, necesitarás conocer el formato gráfico de esa imagen para poder decodificarla correctamente, aunque la biblioteca `matplotlib.pyplot` tiene un método `imread()` bastante inteligente que "deduce" su formato según los primeros bytes de la secuencia.

El problema es que a `imread()` hay que pasarle un fichero y lo que tenemos es una cadena de bytes.

Para este tipo de escenarios existe la biblioteca `io` que tiene clases que te permiten "emular" un fichero cuando lo que tienes es una cadena de bytes (o de caracteres).

En este caso el truco sería por tanto:

```
import io
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

im = plt.imread(io.BytesIO(image_bytes))
```

Esto funcionará tanto si `image_bytes` ha sido leido de un fichero (como en el ejemplo que puse antes) como si ha sido obtenido de cualquier otra forma (ej: desde una base de datos, o tras decodificar una cadena en base64 o lo que sea). `io.BytesIO()` emula ser un fichero y cuando otra función (en teste caso `imread()`) intente leer de él, le irá pasando los bytes en cuestión.

Ya solo queda plotear la imagen para verla:

```
plt.imshow(im)
```

[image: Resultado]

Comment: No sé que esta pasando o que estoy haciendo mal, pero al momento de poner el imread(),                   `id_producto = 1
print('Registro con id %d' %id_producto) 
lista=recuperar_carta(conexion, id_producto)
binario=lista[0][3]

im= plt.imread(io.BytesIO(binario))
plt.imshow((im)) `                                        me aparece un error que dice invalid PNG header

Comment: Parece que tu secuencia de bytes no es una imagen png válida. Si haces un `print(binario)` ¿qué ves? (no hace falta la cadena completa, solo los primeros 40 caracteres para hacerme una idea). Otra prueba que puedes hacer. Si haces `open("prueba.png", "wb").write(binario)` y después intentas abrir el fichero prueba.png con un visor de imágenes ¿se ve?

Comment: b'\xff\xd8\xff\xe1\x00VExif\x00\x00MM\ es lo primero que viene en la cadena y si puedo ver el fichero en un visor de imágenes

Comment: Tiene pinta de ser una imagen jpeg en vez de PNG. Por lo que se ve `plt.imread()` espera que lo que le pases sea una imagen PNG. Puedes especificarle qué formato va en realidad con el parámetro `format`. Intenta entonces `im = plt.imread(io.BytesIO(binario), format="jpeg")`

Comment: Si ya con eso funciona, muchas gracias por la ayuda, te lo agradezco mucho